# Random Number Generator - Histogram Construction (Poisson Distribution and Counting Variables)

Tags: c++, random

**This Problem Has Now Been Resolved - Revised Code is Shown Below**

I have a problem here which I'm sure will only require a small amount of tweaking the code but I do not seem to have been able to correct the program.

So, basically what I want to do is write a C++ program to construct a histogram with nbin = 20 (number of bins), for the number of counts of a Geiger counter in 10000 intervals of a time interval dt (delta t) = 1s; assuming an average count rate of 5 s^(-1). In order to determine the number of counts in some time interval deltat I use a while statement of the form shown below:

```
while((t-=tau*log(zscale*double(iran=IM*iran+IC)))<deltat)count++;
```

As a bit of background to this problem I should mention that the total number of counts is given by n*mu, which is proportional to the total counting time T = n*deltat. Obviously, in this problem n has been chosen to be 10000 and deltat is 1s; giving T = 10000s.

The issue I am having is that the output of my code (which will be shown below) simply gives 10000 "hits" for the element 0 (corresponding to 0 counts in the time deltat) and then, of course, 0 "hits" for every other element of the hist[] array subsequently. Whereas, the output which I am expecting is a Poisson Distribution with the peak "hits" at 5 counts (per second).

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer, and I apologise for my poor explanation of the problem at hand! My code is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>                                 // Pre-processor directives to include
#include <ctime>                                    //... input/output, time,
#include <fstream>                                  //... file streaming and
#include <cmath>                                    //... mathematical function headers

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

const unsigned IM = 1664525;                    // Integer constants for                
const unsigned IC = 1013904223;                 //... the RNG algorithm
const double zscale = 1.0/0xFFFFFFFF;           // Scaling factor for random double between 0 and 1
const double lambda = 5;                        // Count rate = 5s^-1
const double tau = 1/lambda;                    // Average time tau is inverse of count rate
const int deltat = 1;                           // Time intervals of 1s
const int nbin = 20;                            // Number of bins in histogram
const int nsteps = 1E4;

clock_t start, end;

int count(0);

double t = 0;                               // Time variable declaration

unsigned iran = time(0);                        // Seeds the random-number generator from the system time

int hist[nbin];                                 // Declare array of size nbin for histogram

// Create output stream and open output file

ofstream rout;
rout.open("geigercounterdata.txt");

// Initialise the hist[] array, each element is given the value of zero

for ( int i = 0 ; i < nbin ; i++ )
    hist[i] = 0;

start = clock();

// Construction of histogram using RNG process

for ( int i = 1 ; i <= nsteps ; i++ ) { 

    t = 0;
    count = 0;

    while((t -= tau*log(zscale*double(iran=IM*iran+IC))) < deltat)
        count++;        // Increase count variable by 1

    hist[count]++;          // Increase element "count" of hist array by 1

}

// Print histogram to console window and save to output file

for ( int i = 0 ; i < nbin ; i++ ) {

    cout << i << "\t" << hist[i] << endl;
    rout << i << "\t" << hist[i] << endl;

}

end = clock();

cout << "\nTime taken for process completion = "
     << (end - start)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) 
     << " seconds.\n";

rout.close();

return 1;

}   // End of main() routine
```

Comment: I think that the problem may have something to do with my initialisation of the variable t, however if I change t to anything above 1 then the same output is produced, and if I alter t to less than 1, the program crashes during run-time.

Comment: You might want to look at `std::poisson_distribution`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not entirely follow you on the mathematics of your while loop; however the problem is indeed in the condition of the while loop. I broke your while loop down as follows:

```
count--;
do 
{
    iran=IM * iran + IC;            //Time generated pseudo-random
    double mulTmp = zscale*iran;    //Pseudo-random double 0 to 1
    double logTmp = log(mulTmp);    //Always negative (see graph of ln(x))
    t -= tau*logTmp;                //Always more than 10^4 as we substract negative
    count++; 
}  while(t < deltat);
```

From the code it is apparent that you will always end up with `count = 0` when `t > 1` and run-time error when `t < 1` as you will be corrupting your heap.

Unfortunately, I do not entirely follow you on mathematics behind your calculation and I don't understand why Poisson distribution shall to be expected. With the issue mentioned above, you should either go ahead and solve your problem (and then share your answer for the community) or provide me with more mathematical background and references and I will edit my answer with corrected code. If you decide for the earlier, keep in mind that Poisson distribution's domain is `[0, infinity[` so you will need to check whether the vale of `count` is smaller than 20 (or your `nbin` for that matter).

Comment: Well, I am basically using the equation t = -tau*ln(z) which comes from the analytical solution to the radioactive decay equation dN/dt = -lambda*N; which gives N = N(0)*exp(-lambda*t). Events that occur at an average rate lambda are separated by an average time tau = 1/lambda. Random times t can then be generated with the required exponential distribution by means of the transformation z = exp(-t/tau); where the random number z is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

Comment: The time delay between each click on a Geiger counter can then be simulated as t = -tau*log(zscale*double(iran = IM*iran + IC)). But for use in a while loop as shown by my code, this needs to be altered to t -= tau*log(zscale*double(iran = IM*iran + IC)) < deltat, in order to find the number of counts within a time interval of 1s.

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining this very well though, am I? Sorry, I'll try to explain this better in a while if I can - I'm tired at the moment so my explanations probably aren't making much sense.

Comment: Alright, so you are basically taking 10 000 particles of mean time 0.2 second and decaying them for one second and trying to find out how many of them decay in the first, second... 1/20th of a second? The part I am finding confusing the most is your `z = exp(-t/tau)` 'transformation' by which you probably refer to [Probability of survival and particle lifetime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay). By using that equation you are basically saying: Ok, here is my random probability that the particle decayed `z` and I want the time at which the particle has this probability.

Comment: Hmmm, no I'm not sure where you got a "mean time of 0.2s" from. Perhaps I have not explained properly. Essentially, I have a radioactive source decaying and thus emitting particles - on average, 5 particles are detected by a hypothetical Geiger Counter every second. What I want to do is find the number of particles detected within 1 second, 10 000 times - and then construct a histogram of this data where the bin numbers range from 0 to 19 (inclusive). I.e. the bin numbers represent the number of particles detected within that 1 second...

Comment: ... whilst the second column of the output should show the frequency that the corresponding number of particles detected "shows up" (which will be determined by the RNG process within the while loop). Ergo, given that the average count rate is 5 counts per second, then I expect the output to give me a distribution peaked at around 5; and I just happen to know that the distribution should be a Poisson Distribution, however my code should not assume that - I just know this from my Physics knowledge of the problem at hand. I hope that I've made this a bit clearer!

Comment: Sorry, I see where you got the 0.2s mean time from - that's the value of tau of course as it's the inverse of the average count rate.

Comment: I understand what you are doing now. First of all, you are setting your `double t = 1E4;` which I am not entirely convinced is correct. IMO you should start with `t = 0` for every of your trial. Then you are going to increment your `t` until it reaches `deltat`. You incerment in such manner that you each cycle add random time taken for Geiger counter to register particle so your process woud look something like this `t=0, t+=0.1, t+=0.3,...` When `t>=deltat` you count the number of incerments and add one to the histogram accordingly.

Comment: Another problem is that you should reset your `counter` after each of your simulated seconds. I still do think there is something wrong with the `z = exp(-t/tau)` transformation because it produces very small random numbers so you will get huge counts of particles each second. Thats what I got so far.

Comment: Ah, okay, the count and time variables were the issues - I set t = 0 and reinitialised count to 0 in the for loop and I have a nice distribution now. Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated! I shall edit the original question with the working code now if I can.